# How to choose sql server for client side installation?

Tags: sql-server

My application requires local database which will be sql server express.

My requirements are

1. My installer should contain sql server
2. server not having any interface means Sql Management studio like or Command line.
   because i don't want to show any information at local end. i just want to collect data from local end and stored at remote end using sync framework.
3. only one Database & it should be single user mode.No other users can access it.even though user also.user can only see his/her data using application.

My questions is which database server is suitable for my requirement?.

sql server client or sql server express or other.?

Comment: did you not make the decision in your first sentence? why not http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL SERVER Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx) is a free SQL Server embedded database.

1. install with installers
2. not having any default interface
3. only one Database & single user mode
4. protected by password

[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx)